# How to unit test multiple dependencies

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I would like to write some unit tests in C# (using NUnit) but I am not sure how to continue.

So I have a class which presents a user-model, DataModel with four properties. I send this model in my ExcelInit constructor.

```
DataModel dm = new DataModel();
dm.PopulateDataModel(holder);

ExcelInit d1 = new ExcelInit(dm);
d1.BeginProcess();
```

and then in BeginProcess I start my actual method.

```
public class ExcelInit
{
    public DataModel _model { get; set; }

    public ExcelInit(DataModel model)
    {
        _model = model;
    }

    public void BeginProcess()
    {
        DataReader dr = new DataReader();
        CellLocation cl = new CellLocation();
        //Gets the corresponding cellAddress for the cell that contains "2x5" from our hidden config-sheet
        var correspondingCellsAddress = cl.FindCorrespondingCellAddress(_model.boxSize);
        //returns the range that we need to copy i.e. the whole range of the box ala B3:AG13
        var srcRange = dr.GetRangeForSourceDestination(correspondingCellsAddress);
        //Last row of sheet 6 (the sheet we populate) with input-boxes
        var lastRow = dr.FindLastRowByName("Your_Data_Sheet") + 3;
        //gets the cell we'll copy our range to
        var destRange = "B" + lastRow.ToString();

        DataHandler dh = new DataHandler();
        dh.CopyBox(srcRange, destRange, _model);
    }
```

but as you can see, I am creating a lot of classes inside my BeginProcess and my teacher told me that I can't be doing that (I need to use DI so I can test). But my question is, how can I use DI when I need to use so many classes inside my method? Or is my method wrong and I shouldn't depend on so many different things?

Comment: Well, you can inject the `DataReader` as paremeter to your method instead of creating it inside. The same applies to your `DataHandler`. But apart from this I can´t see much to inject here. Which classes *specifically* your teacher refers to?

Comment: Nothing specifically, he just always tells me (Inject class using interface into constructor instead of create new keyword) so I can create test but I just dont understand if I then need to not use any new keyword and just put DataReader, DataHandler and CellLocation into DI but if so do I then need to create new instances in the class that calls this method? Then i still use new keyword and i cannot test then

Comment: @8329396 because you should depend on abstractions (Interfaces) instead of specific implementations, when you depend on abstractions you can create a mock and define fake behaviours. Wrapping up, use new when creating ExcelInit, but in the constructor use interfaces so you can use Mock later

Comment: "create new instances in the class that calls this method?" Exactly, that´s what you should do. The point on DI is not **if** you use `new` (even a DI-container has to create instance in some way, be it via reflection or using `new(...)`), but **where**. So in your test-method you create the depndencies - e.g. the reader - so you can simply use them within your system under test instead of creating them there.

Comment: this is discussion you need to have with your teacher. SO should not be your first stop. Go and talk to him / her, ask for an example or some real guidance. Then you will know what to do. No one here can guess what your teacher means / expects. Go and ask.

Answer (score 1):

The point of DI is not to avoid creation of instances. Even a DI-container has to create the instances of your dependencies in some way, e.g. by using reflection.

Instead DI is about **where** to create those instances. Having said this you should not let your system under test (SuT, in your case the class `ExcelInit`) create its own dependencies, but just *inject* them into the system, e.g. by using constructor-injection or just by puting a paremeter to your method:

```
public void BeginProcess(DataReader dr, CellLocation cl, DataHandler dh)
{
    //Gets the corresponding cellAddress for the cell that contains "2x5" from our hidden config-sheet
    var correspondingCellsAddress = cl.FindCorrespondingCellAddress(_model.boxSize);
    //returns the range that we need to copy i.e. the whole range of the box ala B3:AG13
    var srcRange = dr.GetRangeForSourceDestination(correspondingCellsAddress);
    //Last row of sheet 6 (the sheet we populate) with input-boxes
    var lastRow = dr.FindLastRowByName("Your_Data_Sheet") + 3;
    //gets the cell we'll copy our range to
    var destRange = "B" + lastRow.ToString();

    dh.CopyBox(srcRange, destRange, _model);
}
```

Now within your test you have this:

```
var target = new ExcelInit();
target.BeginProcess(new DataReader(), new CellLocation(), new DataHandler());
```

Of course this will execute the exact same instructions. However you can now also do this:

```
var target = new ExcelInit();
target.BeginProcess(new SomeSpecificDataReader(), new CellLocation(), new DataHandler());
```

As you simply inject the reader instead of creating it within your SuT, your actual SuT doesn´t change at all. So in fact your system under test does not depend on a specific **file**,  but instead it depends on the **data**. Where this data is stored should make no difference to your `BeginProcess`-method. For example you could provide another excel-file (assuming your system uses excel-files), an xml-file or even some in-memory data-storage.

Comment: Can you please provide a test case that shows how externalizing creation of DataReader, CellLocation and DataHandler helps creating better test?

Comment: @Euphoric See my `SomeSpecificDataReader`-example. Of course just injecting dependencies will not make your tests automatically better.

Comment: can't understand why this is downvoted, seems logical to me, it would allow a test to mock expected results and test flow?  maybe i'm missing something but +1 to balance things out

Comment: @NDJ Can you please describe how do you expect Excel's classes to be mocked for testing purposes?

Comment: looks to me like you only need to mock FindCorrespondingCellAddress to return something valid?  I've worked on a project where we mocked the expected calls, we didn't exactly re-create all of excel's functionality

Comment: My nit pick is *"classes should depend on abstractions and not concretions"*. Other than that, this is a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Your teacher seems to be confusing you and possibly confused himself.

His suggestion would work if the dependency was something you control. That is not your case. You are using Excel's API directly and injecting the classes that you are creating using new is not going to help you with testability. If you were to follow your teacher's suggestion, you would have to create test doubles for whole of Excel's API, which I assume is impossible, as that API is not designed for testability.

One way to follow your teacher's suggestion would be to create your own API that wraps that of an Excel. That could be made with testability in mind. But looking at your code, I feel that would be just pushing the problem one layer down. You would complicate your solution, while not having automated tests for code that actually matters.

I would recommend asking your teacher to give you example of what he means. And how would injecting those classes improve testability of the code by writing actual test. I'm sure he will too realize his suggestion if not actually helpful in creating more testable code in your scenario.